# Posting multiple values through from a form, to execute PHP/MySQL queries on input

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, echo

getting a bit confused over this problem...

I have an administrative part of my site, where the admin can search for a passenger (by ID number), and the search returns all related data to that passenger. These searches seem fine when using only ONE parameter.

Now, when posting the information from this form...

```
    <form action="search2.php" method="post"> 
<table> 
<tr><td>Aircraft ID:</td><td><input type="text" name="addAircraftID" /></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Aircraft Type</td><td><input type="text" name="addAirType" /></td></tr> 
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" /></td></tr> 
</table> 
 <input type="hidden" name="addaircraft" value="formsub5"/>
</form>
```

It posts the data fine, as in my results.php file, I can with this example (adding an aircraft to the fleet).

```
// Add an aircraft
 $addAircraftID = $_POST['addAircraftID'];
$addType = $_POST['addAirType'];

echo $addAircraftID . $addType;
```

The values that were posted in the previous form are echoed correctly. However, in the following code, it seems that this IF never gets triggered. Is there something different I have to do when in my form I have submitted more than one value?

```
          if (isset($_POST['addaircraft']) && $_POST['addaircraft']=='formSub5') {



echo "Aircraft Added Successfully! Taking you back to your control panel!";
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30;url=http://www.seatselector.net/admin.php">';


 }
```

I've looked online, and unfortunately not been able to find much help, hopefully you guys and girls could assist!

Many thanks,

Tom

Comment: What exactly of if conditions doesn't work? Comparing or isset()? Try this: var_dump($_POST). What will you get?
Also, are you sure this if condition even works? Maybe script finishes before that? Try:

if (your if) {} else { echo 'test'; }

Comment: I was unaware of this function until just now @Truth and ThiefMaster, thanks for updating me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="addaircraft" value="formsub5"/>
```

Value is "formsub5" whereas `$_POST[]` checks for "formSub5".

Case-sensitive strings.

Comment: Thank you, just needed another set of eyes!